# How to insert dropdownlist value, text box value and gridviews selected row together?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

How to insert dropdownlist value, text box value and gridviews selected row together?

Also attached the screenshot of the data insert:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnyQa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCUYI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZUjv.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to prefer a add button that adds a row to the grid, and THEN you let the user edit the one row.

However, assuming you have those text boxes at the top of the screen, enter data, and then click a button to add to the database, and then re-fresh the GV?

I also don't see some button in the top area to add the data?

so, say a button added to the top area?

then this would add the row to the database:

```
    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strSQL =
           "INSERT INTO MyTable (Session, Class, Section, Term, Subject, HighestMark) " +
           "VALUES (@Session, @Class, @Seciton, @Term, @Subject, @HighestMark)";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL,conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Session", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropSession.selecteditem.value;
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Class", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropClass.selecteditem.value;
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Section", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropSection.selecteditem.value;
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Term", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropTerm.selecteditem.value;
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Subject", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropSubject.selecteditem.value;
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@HighestMark", SqlDbType.Int).Value = HighestMark.Text;
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        ReloadGrid(); // call routine to refresh the grid.
    }
```

## Edit: Adding the rows to a new table

Ok, so we are to take the top values, and then process each row of the grid, and take the ones with a check box and "insert" this data into a new table.

Ok, so the code will look like this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = 0";
        DataTable rstData = MyRst(strSQL);

        foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GHotels.Rows)
        {

            CheckBox ckChecked = gRow.FindControl("ckSelected") as CheckBox;

            if (ckChecked.Checked)
            {
                // this row was checked - add a new row
                DataRow MyNewRow = rstData.NewRow();

                MyNewRow["HotelName"] = txtHOtelName.Text;  // exmaple control 
                MyNewRow["City"] = txtCity.Text; // example control above grid 

                // values from grid row
                // tempalted columns, we use find control
                MyNewRow["FirstName"] = (gRow.FindControl("txtFirstName") as TextBox).Text;
                MyNewRow["LastName"] = (gRow.FindControl("txtLastName") as TextBox).Text;

                // if data bound column, then we use cells collection
                MyNewRow["FavorateFood"] = gRow.Cells[5];

                // etc. etc. 

                rstData.Rows.Add(MyNewRow);
            }

        }

        // done adding to table, write/save back to database.
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();

                da.Update(rstData);
            }
        }
    }
```

I also had this helper routine - I often use it all over the palce:

```
    public DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

So, the concept here?

I pulled a blank row (SELECT * from table where ID = 0).

This gets me the database structure - and thus avoids a BOATLOAD of parameters in the sql.

this approach ALSO allows me to add a row to the table, and add "many" rows. And then execute ONE update to the database to write out (save) all the rows in one shot. So, this again reduced quite a bit of messy code.

Comment: what i want to save all the data from upper portion Session, Class, Section, Term, Subject, HighestMark and grid view data roll no, student id, student name, written marks, Oral Marks, Total and average together is a new table. means together Session, Class, Section, Term, Subject, HighestMark, oll no, student id, student name, written marks, Oral Marks, Total and average  want to save in a table for all the student marks enty.

Comment: Ok, which grid rows below do you want to use for this update - all of them? or perhaps only those with that check box checked? Furthermore, are we to update existing rows, or is this to be actual insert of new rows into another table?

Comment: All the field you are seeing on image that i want to save in a new table.
means on the top portion you are seeing 5 drop down list and one textbox and in a gridview you are seeing multiple rows which is fetched from another table, from the grid view multiple checked rows want to save in a new table. but top portion means 5 dropdown and 1 text box will have to insert with checked multiple grid view rows in a new table. please help?

Comment: See my edit, I show how to grab the data from the top part, and then process that with each grid row (checked ones only), and send the results out to a given table.

Comment: i also want to insert outside of gridview  i.e. dropdown and textbox  with the gridview checked multiple rows.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what the sample code does. It takes some values from the controls above the gv (as per comments - you replace and put as many lines of code for your plane jane controls above the gv. then the next section takes values from the gv - (templated controls if you have), then next section takes values from the gv (cells()) if you have any. These values are combined into ONE data row - added to the datatabe. we do this for each row in the gv (well, first we check the check box). The result is combined rows of data from both - and then we write out the table to sql server.

Comment: I mean I don't have your control names, but you just replace in the code the names of YOUR control names. For the cbo boxes, use MyComboBox.selectedItem.Value (or .Text). However, the code as posted does as you ask. So, we are inserting new rows to a target table here. It is possible that you wanted to update rows of data - but then again, that's not what you ask for. This example assumes a insert - (and insert means add new rows to a target table).  So, the posted code takes values from controls above the gv, takes values from the gv row  - puts in new row for the target table, and then saves